# Extracting content data from webpages

Tags: web-scraping

I'm looking to get structured article data from webpage urls. So far I've found these two services http://www.diffbot.com/ and http://embed.ly/extract/demos/nlp. Are there better alternatives or is it worthwhile to write the code to do this myself?

Answer (score 0):

I have done web scraping / content extract for quite some time now.

For me the best approach is to write a Chrome content extension and automate the browser with their API. This requires that you know Javascript and HTML. In one of my recent projects I use a background page with a couple of editable divs to configure the scraping session. I have some buttons on the background page to start the process. The background page loads a JS script which listens to click events of the buttons.

When one of the buttons is clicked I add a new tab for the scraping session with chrome.tab.create. The background js also defines some chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener to inject content scripts when the tab url contains a specific page/domain name.

The content script then does the scraping job for example selecting some elements with jquery, regular expressions etc and finally send a message with an object back to background JS using chrome.runtime.sendmessage. The background JS script listens to messages with chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener and acts based on the content being extracted.

The extension also automates web databases by clicking for example the next page links.

I have added a timing setting to control the amount of links being clicked / tabs being opened per minute so that the access is slowed down on purpose and too much crawling is avoided.

Finally the results are being uploaded to a database with an AJAX call and inserted with a PHP page into MySQL.

When the extension runs the next time it compares the keys/links which already exist in the database with another AJAX call and ensures that only new information is being extracted.

I have also built extension like the above with Firefox but the best and easiest solution for me is a Chrome/Chromium content extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to skip the code, and are looking for a simple software for web scraping / ETL applications, I'd suggest [Foxtrot](http://www.enablesoft.com/foxtrot-automation-software/). It's easy enough to use and doesn't require coding. I use it to scrape data from certain gov't websites and dump it into an Excel spreadsheet for reporting purposes.